# beep in WinCE , it possible ?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, audio

is it possible to make beep in WinCE ?

i try and i get an error

Comment: [This blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/31/PlayingTonesInTheCompactFramework.aspx) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .net framework methods for beeing are not available in the CF version of the framework.  The best way to get a beep sound is to PInvoke into the MessageBeep function.  The PInvoke signature for this method is pretty straight forward

```
[DllImport("CoreDll.dll")]
public static extern void MessageBeep(int code);

public static void MessageBeep() {
  MessageBeep(-1);  // Default beep code is -1
}
```

This blog post has an excellent more thorough example: [http://blog.digitforge.com/?p=4 (on archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20090601181423/http://blog.digitforge.com/?p=4)

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  P/Invoke [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909766.aspx) or [sndPlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909803.aspx) or [MessageBeep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930642.aspx).  See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/8d96cca1-7883-473b-92db-c6b9f928506d/) or [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/06/03/148142.aspx) or [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29657361/the-old-cfnet-beep-que.aspx).  It's amazing what 30 seconds with a search engine can turn up.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to play one of the default system sounds and using .net runtime 2.0+ (and framework v 3.5+), then you can use the **System.Media.SystemSounds** class (no need for PInvoke or WinAPI calls), like so:

```
//available system sounds
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
System.Media.SystemSounds.Question.Play();
```

Note that the user won't hear anything if they have disabled or muted system sounds.

However, if you are looking to play an arbitrary tone, then the above answers involving WinAPI or PInvoke are what you need to look at.

Comment: That would work if Compact Framework had Media available.  It does not.

Comment: Sure it does.  The calls I posted are examples from working code.  Of course not all hardware has sound support, so maybe you're limited to the default beep or none at all.

Comment: .NET 2.0 has media.  CF.NET 2.0 does not.  I believe it wasn't added until CF.NET 3.5.  If you are using CF.NET 2.0 and have access to System.Media then someone added that namespace outside of Microsoft's doing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsound(v=vs.90).aspx

.NET Framework
Supported in: 3.5, 3.0, 2.0
.NET Compact Framework
Supported in: 3.5

Comment: Ah, so I should clarify I meant 2.0 runtime, not framework.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple beep in Compact Framework you don't need all that import nonsense.  Besides, depending on the hardware you'll only have access to the default beep anyway.  Just use:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Beep()
```

Answer (score 0):

in farmework 3.5 posibble.

My solution for generate diffrent sound.

```
    Beep()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Beep()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
    Beep()
```