# Can we Trigger Beep Sound In Data logic Memoir windows C.E 5.0?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

My Boss Want me to add beep sound in datalogic memoir as a trigger if the output is correct or not. But my problem is i do not know how to do it.
Did you guys successfully make it beep?

Comment: possible duplicate of [beep in WinCE , it posible ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476290/beep-in-wince-it-posible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: [beep in WinCE , it possible ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476290/beep-in-wince-it-posible) first answer, second sentence.

Besides that.. I beep succesfully all the time... I think..